# How do I compare datetime with value from datepicker?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime, compare

I need to compare the chosen date with the date in a database and return values within the date range but keep getting incorrect format. The date format in the database is 2016-01-02 00:00:00.000 (from one of the rows)

I am using the code below but am unable to compare and keep getting"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Help?

```
protected void RadPushButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(RadDatePickerStart.SelectedDate.ToString());
        string s = startDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM");
        startDate = DateTime.Parse(s+"12:00:00 AM");
        // DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(RadDatePickerEnd.SelectedDate.ToString());
        EMCSettlementManager man = new EMCSettlementManager();
        Grid.DataSource = man.GetSTL010(r => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime( r.settlement_date) >= startDate);
        Grid.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Which parse is throwing that error?

Comment: Why do you cast the `DateTime` to `String` and back? DateTime does not store display format, only string representations of DateTime does.

Comment: Don't fiddle around with strings and `DateTime.Parse` if you already have `DateTimes`. `DateTime` has methods like `AddHours`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare dates, make sure all values are of type `DateTime`, not `String`.

Try something like this:

```
DateTime startDate = RadDatePickerStart.SelectedDate;
EMCSettlementManager man = new EMCSettlementManager();
Grid.DataSource = man.GetSTL010(r => r.settlement_date >= startDate);
```

If you want to get rid of the time-part, you could do something like this:

```
DateTime startDate = RadDatePickerStart.SelectedDate.Date;
```

If the field in the database is a string-type, not a datetime, please convert it to a Date(Time)-type. Using strings everywhere is a bad choise, alsnog known as 'stringly typed'. (See: https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)

Comment: I had tried that but had gotten "Cannot implicitly convert 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast))" so i thought the date format might be different like yyyymmdd instead of yyyyddmm, which is why I tried to make it into a string to change it. What I was missing in the datepicker was the ".value". 

DateTime startDate = RadDatePickerStart.SelectedDate.value;

It works now. Thanks!